# Understand a Python regex "[^A-Za-z|\s]|(x)\1{1,}"

Tags: regex, python-re

The first part `[^A-Za-z|\s]` is easy to understand. It is to exclude letters and space. However I don't understand the second part `(x)\1{1,}`, especially `\1`. I was thinking it is to catch a pattern like `x1` or `x111` but when running it it turns out that it is not.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hfBHrE/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's regex back-references, you could find out more about it [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

The second part `(x)\1{1,}` means looking for letter `x` which followed by repeated letter `x`, then captured it to 1st group.

Comment: Clarification/correction: look for letter `x`, capture it into the 1st group, then find one or more repetitions of it. (We may be saying the same thing, but I wanted to make sure "it" refers to the single `x`, not the repetition.)